# Show selected item on RecyclerView in Sync with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get a ViewPager and a RecyclerView to work in sync in displaying an image. The ViewPager contains an ImageView which shows a full sized image and the recycler view shows thumbnails of previous and upcoming images.

If the user swipes on the ViewPager then the RecyclerView moves left/right in sync. If the user scrolls and then clicks a photo, the ViewPager sets that position.

This all works, just giving background to my app.

The part I am stuck on is showing a border around the thumbnail that is currently selected in the RecyclerView **from onPageSelected**. The element which is considered selected is the one that is currently show on the ViewPager

A lot of the other questions deal with this problem using the onClickListener. My onClickListener just calls

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(index)
```

So any time an item is selected, onPageSelected is called, either naturally from the ViewPager or from the click event. So this is where I feel I need to set the border.

So far I'm using a bit of a hack since the number of images is only 20.

```
for (int i = 0, ii = recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount(); i < ii; i++) {
        //RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(recyclerViewAdapter.getItemId(i));
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

        if (holder instanceof RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder) {
            if (i == position) {
                ...
                ((RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder) holder).getViewHolderContainer().setBackground(border);
            } else {
                ((RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder) holder).getViewHolderContainer().setBackground(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work. If get's the right position since I'm provided that by the ViewPager but neither method for retrieving the ViewHolder at 'position' seems to work.

So, after all that, my question is if anyone can recommend me a clean way (or really even a hack at this point) that will let me update the current position of an element based on the position from onPageSelected of the ViewPager.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: did notifyItemChanged(position) to update that position viewholder

Comment: Hi ankitagrawal. Nothing is changed about the dataset. All I am doing is structurally changing an attribute about the view. Incase I was wrong however, I did try it and no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up getting this working using two interfaces. No ugly looping hacks required.

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener and OnChildAttachStateListener.

Basically my issue was that if I scrolled away from the currently selected item in the RecyclerView then I couldn't unselect that item later because the ViewHolder was recycled or null. Basically I couldn't access the previous view to unselect it so multiple items would end up selected when you scroll through it.

So with the ViewPager it was easy.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
    int previousItemPos = currentItemPos; //currentItemPos is a class attr
    currentItemPos = position;
    int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()
    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) { //portrait
        portraitScroll(position) //scrolls the recyclerView to currently selected item based on viewWidth
    } else if .. landscape do the same
    changeItem(position, previousItemPos);
}

@Override
public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
    int childPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    if (childPosition == currentItemPos) {
        highlightItem(view); //applies an effect
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildViewDetachedToWindow(View view) {
    unHighlightItem(view);
}

private void changeItem(int newItem, int oldItem) {
    ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(recyclerView.getItemId(newItem));
    if (holder instance of RecyclerViewHolder) {
        highlightItem((RecyclerViewHolder) holder).getViewHolderContainer());
    }
    ViewHolder oldHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(recyclerView.getItemId(oldItem));
    if (oldHolder instance of RecyclerViewHolder) {
        unHighlightItem((RecyclerViewHolder) holder).getViewHolderContainer());
    }
```

So basically each time we scroll so that the currently selected item in the ViewPager goes out of sight, we unselect it when it is detached. If we scroll back to it and the position hasn't changed, we reselect it.

If the ViewPager changes item, first we scroll to that item based on the width of the each RecyclerViews view, then we select it in onPageSelected.

Comment: This is awesome. i was facing the same problem and your answer helped me solve it. kudos matt

Comment: Could you please post the entire code? Because I got to solve the same problem, but your solution in my case doesn't work.

Comment: @MachoProgrammer It was part of a challenge given to me for an interview about 6 months ago. Here is the github for the project. Look for FragMain.java.
https://github.com/Trestal/FlickrLab